# How to send a differently formatted DateTime to server in Bootstrap DateTimePicker than the one shown to user

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker

Suppose you want to show the user a date this way:

`2017-03-22 22:53`

But you want the form to send `2017-03-22T22:53:00-03:00` to the server.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the field's value at submit event.

```
var options = {
    'sideBySide': true,
    'showTodayButton': true,
    'useCurrent': true,
    'extraFormats': [moment.ISO_8601]
};
var $dpStart = $('#start-date');
var $dpEnd = $('#end-date');
$dpStart.datetimepicker(options);
$dpEnd.datetimepicker(options);
$('#the-form').on('submit', function(event){
    $dpStart.val($dpStart.data("DateTimePicker").date().format());
    $dpEnd.val($dpEnd.data("DateTimePicker").date().format());
});
```